# Replace every second occurency of a substring, Java

Tags: java, string

Trying to replace every second occurence of "Object-oriented programming" substring in a given string "text". I am a beginner in Java and the aim of the task is to use only String class methods.
Below is what I came up with so far. Thanks in advance for any help)

```
public class ExerciseString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Object-oriented programming is a programming language model organized around objects rather than \"actions\" and data rather than logic. Object-oriented programming blabla. Object-oriented programming bla.";
        changeToOOP(s);
    }

    static void changeToOOP (String text) {
        String str = "Object-oriented programming"; // добавить игнорирование регистра
        String str2 = "OOP";

        int index = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (true) {
            index = text.indexOf(str, index);

            if (index != -1) {
                count++;
                index += str.length();

                if (count % 2 == 0){
                    text = text.replace(text.substring(index - str.length(), index), str2);
                }

            }  else {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really nice, that you show us your code but it would be even nicer, if you'd add a question to your post. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) replaces every occurrence and therefore its use for your requirement is not right. You can use

```
text = text.substring(0, index) + str2 + text.substring(index + str.length());
```

Note that `0 % 2==0`; therefore, if you want to replace the occurrence number second, fourth, sixth and so on, use `count % 2 != 0` in the inner `if` block. Also, increment `index` and `count` after processing the previous `index` and `count` values i.e. move the following after the inner `if` block:

```
count++;
index += str.length();
```

**Demo**:

```
public class ExerciseString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Object-oriented programming is a programming language model organized around objects rather than \"actions\" and data rather than logic. Object-oriented programming blabla. Object-oriented programming bla.";
        changeToOOP(s);
    }

    static void changeToOOP(String text) {
        String str = "Object-oriented programming"; // добавить игнорирование регистра
        String str2 = "OOP";

        int index = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (true) {
            index = text.indexOf(str, index);
            if (index != -1) {
                if (count % 2 != 0) {
                    text = text.substring(0, index) + str2 + text.substring(index + str.length());
                }
                count++;
                index += str.length();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

> Object-oriented programming is a programming language model organized
> around objects rather than "actions" and data rather than logic. OOP
> blabla. Object-oriented programming bla.

Comment: Hey Arvind.  Welcome back!  Your expertise has been missed.  Regarding the answer.  The OP said replace every second string.  I presume that means skip the first.

Comment: @WJS Thank you. The main problem with OP's solution is the use of `String::replace` which I have mentioned as the second point. I have restructured my answer to make it the first point. Your point regarding the position of replacement makes sense to me. I have considered this point as well in this update.

Comment: Thank you! I was clearly missing the idea of using count % 2 != 0 in the if block. Also it is a helpful advice to concatenate the final string using the substrings. You have answered my question fully)